# using switch to call functions javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to call functions using switch. I can see my console.log("test") but it wont reach my first function commercial() any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function elevatorCalc() {
    console.log("test")
    //const floors = document.getElementById("resinput_number-of-floors");
    const value = document.getElementById('building-type').value;
    switch(value) {
        case 'commercial':
            commercial();           
            break;
        case 'residential':
            residential();
            break;
        case 'corporate':
            corpo();
            break;
        case 'hybrid':
            hybrid();
            break;
                
    }
           
} 

  function commercial() {
        const elevators = document.getElementById("comminput_number-of-elevators"); 
        console.log(elevators, "test2")
        const liftCages = elevators.value;
        document.getElementById('output_elevator-amount').value = liftCages;
  }
```

Comment: Put the functions into an object, and call like `obj[value]();`, no `switch` needed at all.

Comment: What is the ouput of `console.log(document.getElementById('building-type').value);` ? PS: for me it works. SO I think the value isn't only commercial or someething

Comment: @Elikill58 if I put it before the switch it works it matches my dropdown inputs but once its inside the switch nothing.

Comment: *once its inside the switch* - what does this mean?  Your provided code does not have `doc.getEl..("building-type").value` "inside" the switch

Comment: It's trivial to show that your code *as provided* works as expected:  https://jsfiddle.net/wc0kqLf7/   So it may be how/when you're calling your code or the HTML doesn't match the selector / value.  Please provide a complete [mcve] that *demonstrates* your issue as, at present, there's no issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Teemu's answer actually seems to be the best.

Why don't you try and put your functions into an object, such as:

```js
  const object = {
    commercial: () => {
      const elevators = document.getElementById("comminput_number-of-elevators"); 
      console.log(elevators, "test2")
      const liftCages = elevators.value;
      document.getElementById('output_elevator-amount').value = liftCages;
    },
    residential: () => {...},
    corpo: () => {...},
    hybrid: () => {...}
  };

  function elevatorCalc() {
    console.log("test")
    //const floors = document.getElementById("resinput_number-of-floors");
    const value = document.getElementById('building-type').value;
    object[value]();
    }
```